# Server sometimes drops AJAX requests

Tags: jquery, apache, performance, centos

My customer's web application sometimes drops AJAX requests.

It's a LAMP site.  Regular browser requests are uninhibited.  The web app includes a slide show and that goes right on working.

However, logins involve an AJAX request (jQuery) and a couple times a day, the login requests will not work.  The problem clears up in about 5 minutes.

When logins are failing, users logged in can do most operations but if they're doing other operations involving AJAX requests (certain add/edit operations), those also do not respond.

The Apache logs do not record the requests.

The problem is reported to always occur at the same time in the hour 40-45 minutes past the hour.  I haven't proven this, but the customer is fairly sure.

Figuring out what happens at that time of the hour is one approach I'm working on. The obvious cron job fires every 15 minutes, not just as the 40-45 mark.

But WHAT kind of thing am I looking for?  Both TOP and my VM stats indicate normal usage of CPU & RAM.  The VM stats indicate normal network & disk usage.

I've upgraded to the latest jQuery and I've moved my static files off to a separate server running Lighttpd.  The DB is on another VM on the same host.  Its usage stats fail to show anything unusual at the problem times as well.

What else should I be looking at?

Thanks!

Comment: If the requests aren't hitting the server look into firewall and networking issues. Get packet captures from when things are working and when they don't and see how they differ (on both the server and client ends).

Comment: How, @EtanReisner? I'm running IPTables on the VM. The firewall that controls access to the host doesn't seem to offer any logging. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Out of scope for debugging here a bit. Get the packet captures and start with them.

Comment: @EtanReisner, can you recommend a utility / application to capture the packets?  Isn't the premise that something between the client and the virtual machine is filtering them out?  Should I be taking this up with the data center personnel?

Thanks!

Comment: `wireshark` and `tcpdump` are the most common ones in my experience. It could be some device in the middle. It could be the server firewall. It could be a firewall in middle. It could be an overloaded switch/router. If you can reliably determine that the requests are *not* reaching the server when this happens and you have datacenter/networking staff then yes, ask them.